Can the ed editor be configured to automatically create backup files?
Is there a way to have ed create backups of the file currently loaded into the buffer. On occasion I have inadvertently overwritten my file and found it's not recoverable.  I.e. making a backup file with a tilde appended to the original file name (e.g., myfile.txt~), which would contain the previous version of the file.

Answer seems to be "No". But one backup is not much safer than no backup if the name is fixed. I keep an audit trail for every significant edit, which I can examine with diff to find when I introduced a feature (or a bug). I can see tarConfig.V16, but I believe I had a .V83 on one project, due to a prevaricating client.

The ed editor does not provide a backup facility (or any way to configure it, at all). Writing the editing buffer back to disk with the w command overwrites the original file.
It is up to you to edit a copy of your original data or save the text with a new filename, either by saving using w some-filename or using f some-filename to set the name of the file at the start of the editing session, followed by w when you want to write to the buffer to the file.
Some modern filesystems provide snapshotting facilities that let you retrieve the overwritten data, or if you overwrote it in error, fetch it from a recent backup.

Years ago I wrote a wrapper tool around vi that could trivially be modified to support ed or any other file-modifying tool. It takes a backup of the file before launching the editor, and when the editor is finished it compares the result with the original.
The gist is pretty much like this. It's definitely not perfect - for example it will choke if you have a file name that starts with a dash (-) - but it works for me and it may work for you.
#!/bin/sh
#
editor='ed'                 # Derive this from "$0" if you want to be fancy
date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')    # Use date/time if you want greater granularity

# Save each file
for file in "$@"
do
    [ -f "$file" ] && cp -pf "$file" "$file.$date.$$.tmp"
done

# Edit the file(s) using your preferred editor
"$editor" "$@"
ss=$?

# Compare edited and saved copies
for file in "$@"
do
    tmpf="$file.$date.$$.tmp"

    if [ -f "$tmpf" ]
    then
        if [ ! -f "$file" ] || ! cmp -s "$file" "$tmpf"
        then
            # Keep the saved copy as a backup
            [ ! -f "$file.$date" ] && mv -f "$tmpf" "$file.$date"
        fi

        # Delete the temporarily saved copy regardless
        rm -f "$tmpf"
    fi
done

# Return the exit code from the editor itself
exit $ss

I would call this something like bed (backup editor) or bvi and use everything except the first letter of the program name to derive $editor:
progname=${0##*/}       # Program name (without path)
editor=${progname#?}    # Editor to use

